# Reset a stack navigation stack from outside the stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I want to reset my stack navigation stack when I log out a user.  Currently if I log out, my user is taken to my auth screen that is using switchNavigator, and if a user logs back in they are taken to the screen that they were last on when they logged out.  I would like a user to be directed to the customer feed after they log out and then log in again.

My navigator looks like this

```
export const Tabs = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoading,
    Auth: UnAuthenticatedTabs,
    App: AuthenticatedTabs
  },
  {
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);

const UnAuthenticatedTabs = SwitchNavigator({
  LogIn: { screen: SignIn },
  Registration: { screen: Registration },
  ForgotPassword: { screen: ForgotPassword }
})

const AuthenticatedTabs = StackNavigator({
  CustomerFeed: { screen: CustomerFeed,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Customer Feed',
    })
   },
  Customer: { screen: Customer,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Customer'
    })
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me was resetting the stack when the user logs in and is routed to the stackNavigator. Not when trying to reset the stackNavigator when the user is logging out and routed to the switchNavigator.

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'CustomerFeed' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```